# Identity Template specific elements, exclude everything else

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Using the below XML how would I extract only the Address details into a CSV format?

I believe I need to have a style sheet based on the Identity template, though the examples I found are simple and state to the list the elements you want to exclude. Is there a short way to exclude everything except Address and AddressLine?

I am using .NET to process the XLST transformation. The stylesheet I have come up with so far doesn't return anything.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xa;'" />

  <xsl:template match="node()| @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()| @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AddressLine" priority="9">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, ., $quote, $delim)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" priority="0" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
<Sample Version="6" Date="2012-05-11">
  <Header>
    <CreatedDate>2015-12-02</CreatedDate>
    <CreatedTime>10:31:42</CreatedTime>
  </Header>
  <Message Group="1" Type="1" Protocol="1">
    <MessageHeader>
      <MessageReferenceNumber>1</MessageReferenceNumber>
    </MessageHeader>
    <TransactionHeader>
      <ReportPeriodStartDate>2002-04-01</ReportPeriodStartDate>
      <ReportPeriodEndDate>2015-11-30</ReportPeriodEndDate>
    </TransactionHeader>
    <Episode>
      <Person>
        <General>
          <Verified Status="02">
            <Identifier>001</Identifier>
            <PersonName>
              <Name>
                <FirstName>Foo</FirstName>
                <Surname>Bar</Surname>
              </Name>
            </PersonName>
            <Address>
              <AddressLine></AddressLine>
              <AddressLine>Street</AddressLine>
              <AddressLine>Town</AddressLine>
              <AddressLine>City</AddressLine>
            </Address>
          </Verified>
        </General>
      </Person>
      <Session>
        <Input>
          <StartDate>2015-10-31</StartDate>
          <StartTime>17:15:00</StartTime>
        </Input>
        <Output>
          <StatusCode>8</StatusCode>
          <LocationCode>9</LocationCode>
        </Output>
      </Session>
    </Episode>
    <MessageTrailer>
      <MessageReferenceNumber>1</MessageReferenceNumber>
    </MessageTrailer>
  </Message>
  <Message Group="1" Type="1" Protocol="1">
    <MessageHeader>
      <MessageReferenceNumber>2</MessageReferenceNumber>
    </MessageHeader>
    <TransactionHeader>
      <ReportPeriodStartDate>2002-04-01</ReportPeriodStartDate>
      <ReportPeriodEndDate>2015-11-30</ReportPeriodEndDate>
    </TransactionHeader>
    <Episode>
      <Person>
        <General>
          <Verified Status="02">
            <Identifier>002</Identifier>
            <PersonName>
              <Name>
                <FirstName>Foo</FirstName>
                <Surname>Bar</Surname>
              </Name>
            </PersonName>
            <Address>
              <AddressLine></AddressLine>
              <AddressLine>Street</AddressLine>
              <AddressLine>Town</AddressLine>
              <AddressLine>City</AddressLine>
            </Address>
          </Verified>
        </General>
      </Person>
      <Session>
        <Input>
          <StartDate>2015-10-31</StartDate>
          <StartTime>17:15:00</StartTime>
        </Input>
        <Output>
          <StatusCode>8</StatusCode>
          <LocationCode>9</LocationCode>
        </Output>
      </Session>
    </Episode>
    <MessageTrailer>
      <MessageReferenceNumber>2</MessageReferenceNumber>
    </MessageTrailer>
  </Message>
  <Trailer>
    <RecordCount>2</RecordCount>
  </Trailer>
</Sample>
```

Comment: Note that the reason your current XSLT returns nothing is because of the template match `<xsl:template match="*" priority="0" />`. This actually has a higher priority than the identity template (which has a default priority of -0.5). Therefore, this template matches the root element `Sample`, and simply stops processing there. (If you wanted it to skip over the element, and continue processing its children, you would explicitly add an `<xsl:apply-templates />` instruction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the identity transformation template makes sense if you want to create plain text, all you need is a template for the root node

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Address"/>
</xsl:template>
```

then you can write the template doing what you want or need to output for the `Address` or its children `AddressLine`, as you seem to have.

As an alternative, you can exploit the default templates that exist to recursively process child nodes, only you need to make sure you override the ones for `text()` nodes as otherwise all text of all elements would be output.

So either try

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Address"/>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AddressLine">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, ., $quote, $delim)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

or solely an approach like

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(self::Address)]/text()"/>

<xsl:template match="AddressLine">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, ., $quote, $delim)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In both cases I am not sure which exact result you want in terms of lines produced, so some adjustments to insert or add line breaks might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add explicit template priorities, just use a template that matches `AddressLine` and another to keep all text nodes from being output by default.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xa;'" />


  <xsl:template match="AddressLine">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, ., $quote, $delim)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Text Output**

```
"","Street","Town","City","","Street","Town","City",
```

If you expected the output to be different, explain what should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

One short way is "redefining" built-in template rules and only copying the selected one - in this case `Address` and child-nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Address">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which results in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Address>
    <AddressLine/>
    <AddressLine>Street</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>Town</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>City</AddressLine>
</Address>
<Address>
    <AddressLine/>
    <AddressLine>Street</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>Town</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>City</AddressLine>
</Address>
```